# Changing AWIS call into async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have this function:

```
function AlexaCall(website) {
    var awis = require('awis');

    var client = awis({
        key: keys.alexa.public,
        secret: keys.alexa.secret,
    });

    let responseData = [];

    client({
        Action: 'UrlInfo',
        'UrlInfo.Shared.ResponseGroup': 'Rank',
        'UrlInfo.1.Url': 'lupomontero.com',
        'UrlInfo.2.Url': 'yahoo.com',
        'UrlInfo.3.Url': 'weibo.com',
        'UrlInfo.4.Url': 'github.com',
        'UrlInfo.5.Url': 'monono.org'
    }, (err, data) => {
        // res.length === 5
        // data is an array with a response object for each domain
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            //res.write(item.trafficData.dataUrl);
            responseData.push(item);
        });
        console.log(responseData);
        callback(null, JSON.stringify(responseData));
    });
}
```

Is it possible to edit it to act like this one?

```
async function PageSpeedCall(website) {
    var pagespeedCall = `https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=https://${website}&strategy=mobile&key=${keys.pageSpeed}`;
    // second call
    var results = await fetch(pagespeedCall);
    return await results.json();
}
```

The first one uses the [AWIS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awis). The docs are quite clear, but I need to be able to call the function like this:

```
async function callAllSites(websites) {
    var psRes = [];
    var mozRes = [];
    for (let website of websites) {
        psRes.push(await PageSpeedCall(website));
        mozRes.push(await MozCall(website));
    }
    return await {'ps': psRes, 'moz': mozRes};
    // return await [psRes, mozRes];
    // return psRes;
}

callAllSites('google.com','stackoverflow.com')
    .then(results => {
        // console.log(results.ps[3].error)
        // console.log(results.error)
        // console.log(results.ps[0].formattedResults.ruleResults)
        console.log(results);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    .then(() => console.log('done'));
```

I need to pass the `websites[]` array, because that's what's comming from the view, and user can pass multiple values into it. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: async/await works with Promises (async functions return a promise, await waits on a promise) so you just need to convert the callback api of `awis` into a promise api, there are a number of npm modules for it, search "promisify"

Comment: I'm afraid it's either not that simple or I don't get it. promisify accepts functions which wait for a callback, and in my case I'm just calling one.

Comment: `const client = promisify(awis({key, secret})); const data = await client(query);`  awais returns a callback function, you wrap that callback function into a promise and then you can await it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of promisifying it manually.

```
const awis = require('awis');

async function AlexaCall(website) {

    const client = awis({
        key: keys.alexa.public,
        secret: keys.alexa.secret,
    });

    let responseData = [];

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      client({
        Action: 'UrlInfo',
        'UrlInfo.Shared.ResponseGroup': 'Rank',
        'UrlInfo.1.Url': 'lupomontero.com',
        'UrlInfo.2.Url': 'yahoo.com',
        'UrlInfo.3.Url': 'weibo.com',
        'UrlInfo.4.Url': 'github.com',
        'UrlInfo.5.Url': 'monono.org'
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        // res.length === 5
        // data is an array with a response object for each domain
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            //res.write(item.trafficData.dataUrl);
            responseData.push(item);
        });
        console.log(responseData);
        resolve(JSON.stringify(responseData));
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Well it does make the call. The problem is I'm getting `Error: XML response missing aws:Response!`. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Ok there is some logic issues on my side/, but the code seems to work. Thanks!